# I can't curl. How do I do DNS resolution on WSL 2 on a WIndows 10 VM running on VMWare Fusion/macos 10.15.7 (Catalina)?

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion, wsl2

The setup:

- A MacBook Pro, running Catalina
- VMWare Fusion Player Version 12.1.0
- A Windows 10 Dev VM, image from developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/virtual-machines/
- Using the builtin ubuntu WSL app/thing that comes with the Windows 10 VM

The problem:

- I can't ping google.com in WSL 2, but I *can* ping 216.58.193.78 (which resolves to google.com). Needless to say, the things I'd like to do in that V-VM, like run `curl` and `git clone`, are also broken.

VMWare settings:

- 4 GB
- 2 Processors
- Processors & Memory/Advanced options/Enable hypervisor applications in this VM is *ON*
- Network Adapter: "Internet Sharing/Share with my Mac" (i.e. NAT)

Some more details:

The nameserver in `/etc/resolve.conf` is different on every run. If I replace it with the nameserver from the host it makes no difference - ping on a domain name gives error messages: usually `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

Using [Control Panel | Network & Internet | Network Connections | Change Adapter Settings ] in the VM, it tells me that `vEthernet (WSL)` has no ipv4 or ipv6 network access, which seems false, as I *can* ping remote IPs. But maybe that app is trying to do some kind of echo on WSL, and that fails. I dunno.

I also tried the sequence at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5336#issuecomment-653881695 resetting the network, but that didn't work either.

This seems to be a DNS problem, not a network problem, as ping on an external IP addr worked.

The question:

How do I network from WSL?

Comment: Under a "working" WSL2, the address that is getting auto-generated in `/etc/resolv.conf` should be the one that is assigned to `vEthernet (WSL)`, which is not getting an address in your case.  What's odd is that it is also used for the default route out from WSL, and that's working for you.  What *is* your default route in the WSL instance right now (`ip route show`)?